# gae error : Error: Server Error, how to debug it 

Tags: python, google-app-engine, debugging

when i upload my project to google-app-engine , it show this :

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.
```

why ?

how can i debug this error ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the logs in the online administrative console of your App Engine account.  That's where the info about the "why" hides;-).

Incidentally, it's very unlikely (although not impossible) that you'd immediately see such an error on the actual online App Engine without hints in your local development toolkit environment -- have you thoroughly exercised your app in the SDK before uploading it?

Comment: thanks ,i was lucky find the error, the answer is the chinese word ,thanks